# I want to extract sku, quantity, price from a made order for each of the bought items in order using event sales_order_place_after

Tags: orders, event-observer, magento-1

I can catch the event `sales_order_place_after` with no problems, but now I have a problem because I can't get `Mage::log(var_export($observer->getEvent()->getOrder()));` to work because the output is too big. I need sku, quantity and price for each of the items that are in that particular order. How can I do this? I guess if I knew which class `->getOrder()` returns this would not be a problem, but I don't. Which class does this method return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
$order = $observer -> getEvent() -> getOrder();
$items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
foreach($items as $item){
    $sku = $item->getSku();
    $price = $item->getPrice();
     $quantity = $item->getQtyOrdered();
}
```

Comment: In order to fully answer the question, can you also write how to get price and quantity, and maybe configurable option, if that item is from a configurable product?

Comment: Please update your code so that i can understand  your requirement.

Comment: You already answered.

Answer (score 0):

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
$items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
foreach($items as $item){
    echo $item->getSku();
    echo $item->getPrice();
    echo $item->getQtyOrdered();
}
```

Comment: If i run https://paste.ofcode.org/37ccujDxcru9uDgYkE2PMiy   my log file name 35 instead of event.log, may i know what is the issue? screenshot -> https://snipboard.io/62r8hA.jpg @Pradeep Sanku thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
$items = $order->getAllItems();
foreach($items as $item){
    $sku = $item->getSku();
    $qty = $item->getQtyOrdered();
    $price = $item->getPrice();
}
```